# Verificar se um ou mais servidor(es) AD está(ão) ativo(s)

Tags: javascript, openldap

É possível, através de JavaScript, verificar se um servidor AD está ativo?

Na minha empresa há 4 servidores e gostaria de saber qual está ativo para fazer uma autenticação via AD.

Comment: A verificação pode ser feita por um ping?

Comment: Creio que não... uma vez que a check seria através de JavaScript.
Na verdade não sei se da para fazer um ping e retornar true or false pelo JavaScript

Comment: O ideal seria você realizar uma query LDAP, mas não sei se é possível via JS.

Comment: @LeonardoVinicius: Perguntei porque achei esse [código](https://github.com/jdfreder/pingjs) que simula um ping em JavaScript. Ele tenta gravar uma informação no servidor, se o servidor negar ou permitir a operação significa que está ativo(true). Se o servidor não responder é porque não está disponível(false).

Comment: Cara... acho que vai funcionar. Vou ver se dá certo!